# My OnClick() function on inspector only shows MonoScript

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I was working on a story telling like decision making rpg and of course for the dialogues to continue on I needed to put functions on the OnClick() part of the inspector of the button, which was working the other day, when I placed a new code to go to the next scene. The drop down only shows this:

[image: SceneHandler Function (for going to other scenes)]

So the new script I added the other day resulted to this. I thought that this particular script alone had this issue so I removed it but the other scripts in the other buttons also ended up like this:

[image: Activator function (For enabling and disabling objects involved)]

I tried going back to my last save to try and save the functions but to no avail. They all ended up like this and I don't know how to fix this. Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

This is the code for both functions in case I missed something or messed something up:

Activator code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Activator : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject NextDialogue;
public GameObject CurrentDialogue;
public GameObject NextButton;
public GameObject OtherNextButton;

public void Activation()
{      
    if (NextDialogue != null)
    {
        NextDialogue.SetActive(true);
    }
    if (CurrentDialogue != null)
    {
        CurrentDialogue.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (NextButton != null)
    {
        NextButton.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (OtherNextButton != null)
    {
        OtherNextButton.SetActive(true);
    }
    
}
}
```

SceneHandler Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
public string SceneName;

public void NextScene()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneName);
}
}
```

Comment: Add `gameobject` then put your script there after that select your `game object` under `runtime only`

Answer (score 1):

You want to put your button somewhere inside a canvas, and also put your script for the button inside the canvas, then put the canvas in the buttons thing to show the functions:
[how to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqzOI.png)

Comment: Ah yes thank you, didn't realize I was being an idiot in the assignment of things there